# Redirecting all requests to a static page with nginx

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to redirect all the requests hitting my page to an image. Inside my default.conf I have this:

```
server {
listen       80;
server_name  localhost;

#charset koi8-r;
#access_log  /var/log/nginx/log/host.access.log  main;

location / {
    try_files $uri  $uri/ /usr/share/nginx/html/10343632.jpeg;
}

#error_page  404              /404.html;

# redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
#
error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
location = /50x.html {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
}

# proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
#
#location ~ \.php$ {
#    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
#}

# pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
#
#location ~ \.php$ {
#    root           html;
#    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
#    fastcgi_index  index.php;
#    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
#    include        fastcgi_params;
#}

# deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
# concurs with nginx's one
#
#location ~ /\.ht {
#    deny  all;
#}
 }
```

the jpeg file is the image and it's located in /usr/share/nginx/html and I have removed all the other files from that directory. Every time I hit the page it gives a :

```
rewrite or internal redirection cycle while internally redirecting to "/usr/share/nginx/html/10343632.jpeg
```

I've also tried :

```
try_files $uri /usr/share/nginx/html/10343632.jpeg;
```

and

```
try_files $uri  /10343632.jpeg;
```

and got the same error. The point of this is to serve an image no matter what the user requested.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The location section must account for root such that :

```
  location / {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html/;
    try_files $uri /10343632.jpeg;
}
```

and it'll work!

Comment: THANK YOU! very elegant and simple solution